# Flex/Yacc interpreter that converts toml to JSON

Tags: python, flex-lexer, yacc, ply

I am trying to make a Flex/Yacc interpreter that converts a toml input to json. It was all looking great until I tried to convert the inline tables. Heres is the files I got so far:

lexer.py:

```
import ply.lex as lex

tokens = (
    'COMMENT',
    'EQUALS',
    'COMMA',
    'OBRACKET',
    'CBRACKET',
    'KEY',
    'INLINETABLE',
    'TABLENAME',
    'SUBTABLENAME',
    'STRING',
    'BOOL',
    'FIRSTCLASSDATE',
    'DATE',
    'TIME',
    'INT',
    'REAL',
    'NEWLINE'
)

def t_COMMENT(t):
    r'\#[^\n]*\n*'
    pass

t_FIRSTCLASSDATE = r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}'

t_DATE = r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'

t_TIME = r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'

t_EQUALS = r'\='

t_COMMA = r','

t_OBRACKET = r'\['

t_CBRACKET = r']'

t_KEY = r'[A-Za-z\d_-]+(\.[A-Za-z\d_-]+)*(?=\s=)'

t_INLINETABLE = r'\{[^{}]*\}'

t_TABLENAME = r'(?<=\[)[^\[\]""]+(?=\])'

t_SUBTABLENAME = r'(?<=\[)[^\[\]"]+\.[^\[\]"]+(?=\])'

t_BOOL = r'\b(?:true|false)\b'

t_NEWLINE = r'\n'

def t_STRING(t):
    r'(\"([^\n\\\"]|\\.|\\\n)*\")|(\'([^\n\\\']|\\.|\\\n)*\')'
    t.value = t.value[1:-1]
    return t

def t_REAL(t):
    r'(?<![\'"])-?\d+\.\d+(?![\'"])'
    t.value = float(t.value)
    return t

def t_INT(t):
    r'(?<![\'"])((?<!\d)-)?\d+(?![\'"]|\d|T|-|:|(?<=\d)\s=)'
    t.value = int(t.value)
    return t

t_ignore = " "

def t_error(t):
    print(f"Illegal character {t.value[0]}")
    t.lexer.skip(1)

lexer = lex.lex()
```

parser.py:

```
import ply.yacc as yacc
from lexer import tokens

def merge_dicts(d1, d2):
    for key, value in d2.items():
        if key in d1 and isinstance(d1[key], dict) and isinstance(value, dict):
            merge_dicts(d1[key], value)
        else:
            if isinstance(value, dict) and len(value) == 1:
                k, v = next(iter(value.items()))
                d1[k] = v
            elif isinstance(value, tuple):
                d1[key] = { value[0]: value[1] }
            else:
                d1[key] = value

def p_toml(p):
    '''
    toml : toml inline_table
         | toml keyvalue
         | toml keyvalue_list
         | toml table
         | toml subtable
         | inline_table
         | keyvalue
         | keyvalue_list
         | table
         | subtable
    '''
    if len(p) == 3:
        if isinstance(p[1], dict) and isinstance(p[2], tuple):
            merge_dicts(p[1], {p[2][0]: p[2][1]})
        elif isinstance(p[1], dict) and isinstance(p[2], list) and len(p[2]) == 2:
            for item in p[2]:
                merge_dicts(p[1], {item[0]: item[1]})
        elif isinstance(p[1], dict) and isinstance(p[2], list) and len(p[2]) == 0:  # handle empty list
            pass
        else:
            merge_dicts(p[1], {p[2][0][0]: p[2][0][1]})
        p[0] = p[1]
    else:
        if isinstance(p[1], tuple):
            p[0] = {p[1][0]: p[1][1]}
        elif isinstance(p[1], list):
            p[0] = dict(p[1])

def p_inline_table1(p):
    '''
    inline_table : KEY EQUALS INLINETABLE NEWLINE
    '''
    parts = p[3].replace('{', '').replace('}', '').split(',')
    d = {}

    for part in parts:
        key, value = [x.strip() for x in part.split('=')]

        value = value.strip('"')

        try:
            value = int(value)
        except ValueError:
            try:
                value = float(value)
            except ValueError:
                pass

        d[key] = value

    p[0] = (p[1], d)

def p_inline_table2(p):
    '''
    inline_table : NEWLINE
    '''
    p[0] = []

def p_keyvalue_list1(p):
    '''
    keyvalue_list : keyvalue_list keyvalue
    '''
    if p[1] is None:
        p[1] = []
    if isinstance(p[2], tuple):
        p[1].append(p[2])
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_keyvalue_list2(p):
    '''
    keyvalue_list : keyvalue_list NEWLINE
    '''
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_keyvalue_list3(p):
    '''
    keyvalue_list : keyvalue
    '''
    p[0] = [p[1]]

def p_keyvalue_list4(p):
    '''
    keyvalue_list : NEWLINE
    '''
    p[0] = []

def p_keyvalue(p):
    '''
    keyvalue : KEY EQUALS value
    '''
    key_parts = p[1].split('.')
    if len(key_parts) > 1:
        nested_dict = {key_parts[-1]: p[3]}
        for part in reversed(key_parts[:-1]):
            nested_dict = {part: nested_dict}
        p[0] = (key_parts[0], nested_dict)
    else:
        if isinstance(p[3], list):
            value = dict(value=p[3])
            if len(value) == 1 and 'value' in value:
                p[0] = (p[1], value['value'])
            else:
                p[0] = (p[1], value)
        else:
            p[0] = (p[1], p[3])

def p_subtable1(p):
    '''
    subtable : OBRACKET SUBTABLENAME CBRACKET NEWLINE
    '''
    names = p[2].split(".")
    p[0] = [names[0], {names[1]: {}}]

def p_subtable2(p):
    '''
    subtable : OBRACKET SUBTABLENAME CBRACKET NEWLINE keyvalue_list
    '''
    names = p[2].split(".")
    p[0] = [(names[0], {names[1]: dict(p[5])})]


def p_table1(p):
    '''
    table : OBRACKET TABLENAME CBRACKET NEWLINE
    '''
    p[0] = [(p[2], {})]

def p_table2(p):
    '''
    table : OBRACKET TABLENAME CBRACKET NEWLINE keyvalue_list
    '''
    p[0] = [(p[2], dict(p[5]))]

def p_table3(p):
    '''
    table : OBRACKET TABLENAME CBRACKET NEWLINE subtable
    '''
    p[0] = [(p[2], dict(p[5]))]

def p_table4(p):
    '''
    table : OBRACKET TABLENAME CBRACKET NEWLINE inline_table
    '''
    p[0] = [(p[2], (p[5][0], p[5][1]))]

def p_value1(p):
    '''
    value : INT
          | REAL
          | STRING
          | FIRSTCLASSDATE
          | DATE
          | TIME
          | list
    '''
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_value2(p):
    '''
    value : BOOL
    '''
    if p[1].lower() == 'true':
        p[0] = True
    else:
        p[0] = False

def p_list(p):
    '''
    list : OBRACKET nested_values CBRACKET
    '''
    p[0] = p[2]

def p_values1(p):
    '''
    values : value
    '''
    p[0] = [p[1]]

def p_values2(p):
    '''
    values : values COMMA value
    '''
    p[0] = p[1] + [p[3]]

def p_nested_values1(p):
    '''
    nested_values : nested_values COMMA value
    '''
    p[0] = p[1] + [p[3]]

def p_nested_values2(p):
    '''
    nested_values : nested_values COMMA list
    '''
    p[0] = p[1] + [p[3]]

def p_nested_values3(p):
    '''
    nested_values : value
    '''
    p[0] = [p[1]]

def p_nested_values4(p):
    '''
    nested_values : list
    '''
    p[0] = [p[1]]

def p_error(p):
    print(f"Syntax error at line {p.lineno}, column {p.lexpos}, '{p.value}'")

parser = yacc.yacc()
```

main.py:

```
import json
from lexer import lexer
from parser import parser

inp = """
 
title = "TOML Example"  

[owner] 
name = "Tom Preston-Werner" 
dob = 1979-05-27T07:32:00-08:00 

 
[database] 
enabled = true 
ports = [ 8000, 8001, 8002 ] 
data = [ ["delta", "phi"], [3.14] ] 
temp_targets = { cpu = 79.5, case = 72.0 }
"""

def main():
    lexer.input(inp)
    parsed_dict = parser.parse(inp, lexer=lexer)
    json_str = json.dumps(parsed_dict, indent=2)
    print(json_str)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When running main, this error shows up:

> Syntax error at line 1, column 240, '{ cpu = 79.5, case = 72.0 }'
> {}

What I expect is to get the corresponding JSON. If I remove the inline table from the input toml it runs perfectly.

Comment: We need example input and output so we can reproduce your fault.